# Extjs4 Combo's and Stores: Remove filter when queryMode=local?

Tags: extjs4, extjs, store

I'm getting frustrated because my store keeps getting filtered whenever I use it to back a combofield.  Is there any way I can disable this?

**The Scenario**

I have a Store with a `data` field on it; an array of objects loaded when the store is instantiated.  I use this store to drive a bunch of combo's in different areas of my app.  Unfortunately, my combos are applying filters on the store, causing other combos using the same store to only display the filtered values later on, not the whole list.

**Workarounds**

My goofy workaround is to call `combo.getStore().clearFilter()` after I'm done with the combo, but that's going to get old very quick, and probably introduce a bug somewhere, I'm sure.

If I remove `queryMode:'local'` from my combo's config, all is well, except that now the handy type-ahead feature no longer works; I'm just shown a list of items in a drop-down that I can't even navigate around my typing letters of matching items.  That's worse than a regular html `select` tag!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that since the filtering is applied not on the `combo` but on the `store`. You could try creating multiple instances of the same `store` and work with that. Though I don't know if it'll work.

```
Ext.create('combo', {
      //other config
      store : Ext.create('my.store')
});
```

It'll work if you make the `combo` non-editable since no filtering can be applied then. But, as you say, you need the type ahead feature, you'll need to create multiple instances of the `store`.

Answer (score 1):

In light of the fact that combos will add filters on the backing store, hence affecting all combos that use the store within my application, I've opted to add an override to the combo class so it will clear the filter on the store when the combo box is destroyed.

```
Ext.define('MAP.override.Combo', {
    override : 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    initComponent : function()
    {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.on('beforedestroy',function(combo){
            if(combo.leaveFilter === true) return;

            console.log('clearing filter on store');
            combo.getStore().clearFilter();
        });
    }
});
```

it's a bit of a hack, but I do allow for the escape hatch of indicating not to clear the filters, too.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I have found to handle this solution is to add the following listener to the combo:

```
listeners: {
    beforequery: function(queryPlan){
        queryPlan.query = true;
    }
}
```

by default queryPlan.query is the text currently in the combo field which is used for filtering. Setting it to false cancels the query, but setting it to true allows the query to go through without a filter value, therefore keeping all values in the drop down list for all combo fields.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem with ExtJS 4.2 and combo. Store kept being filtered but I couldn't use clearFilter() because after that combo was unusable. My solution, which worked, is this listener on combo:

```
listeners: {
  blur: function(combo) {
    if (combo.queryFilter) {
      combo.queryFilter.setValue('');
      combo.getStore().filter();
    }
  }
}
```